# Align span inside title to the right

Tags: html, css

How can I align subtitle to the right without using float? I need it to be on the same level as title.

```
<h2>Title <span>Subtitle</span> </h2>

h2 {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font-size: 50px;
}

span {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
h2 {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font-size: 50px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:baseline;
}

span {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title <span>Subtitle</span> </h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `position:absolute` property with small adjustments

```css
h2 {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  font-size: 20px;
   position: absolute;
  right: 6px;  
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title <span>Subtitle</span> </h2>
```

Comment: Instead of margin-top, in order to vertically middle align can we have `line-height: 50px` for span.